# typing.cast not casting type in __new__ when used with typing.Protocol

Tags: python, dependency-injection, python-typing

I'm implementing a Dependency Injection library for learning. This is my injectable class:

```py
class Injectable[T]:
    __injection__: type

    def __new__(cls, injection_class: type[T]) -> T:
        if injection_class == Injectable:
            raise ValueError("Injectable cannot be injected.")

        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.__injection__ = injection_class
        return ty.cast(T, self)

    def __getattr__(self, _: str) -> None:
        raise DIConfigurationError()
```

This is example usage:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

from injkt import Bind, Config, Injectable, Injktor, inject_args_deps


class IMailService(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def send_mail(self, subject: str, to: str) -> None:
        ...


class SmtpMailService(IMailService):
    def send_mail(self, subject: str, to: str) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()


injktor = Injktor(
    Config(
        {
            Bind(IMailService, SmtpMailService),
        }
    )
)


@inject_args_deps
def business_logic(mail_service=Injectable(IMailService)):
    mail_service.send_mail("Hello", "world")


business_logic()
```

The type of **mail_service** in the above function is `IMailService`, however if I use `ty.Protocol` instead of `ABC`:

```py
class IMailService(ty.Protocol):
    def send_mail(self, subject: str, to: str) -> None:
        ...
```

The type of **mail_service** in the **business_logic** function changes to `Injectable[IMailService]` which breaks the typings I'm trying to achieve.

I know changing the implementation detail will solve the problem, I'm not trying to figure out other ways for solving the problem, I'm just trying to figure out why this is happening and if this is solvable using the current implementation for DI.

For more reference, this is the github repo: https://github.com/caffeineduck/injkt